# Xcode 7.2 downloading but not installing

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, install

I went through the tedious download process via App Store. The row in the App Store Updates tab said Xcode was installed. But no sign of it in Applications folder.

When I go to the Purchased tab of App Store, the Xcode row has a button labeled "Install". So Xcode was *not* installed? OK, click this button. This just starts *another* 4 GB download. It seems that "install" means "download" and nothing actually installs.

What's up with the App Store? I poked around in the /private/var/.../com.apple.appstore folder but didn't see anything enlightening. I am now downloading the .dmg file directly from the Developer website. (Slow connection: 16 hr download!)

Answer (score 1):

Download it from here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Just log in with your Apple Account and download Xcode 7.2

Answer (score -2):

you need to delete Xcode in local machine and then login Appstore to download this app.